# Stationary Time series is showing better results when predicting(ARIMA) after differencing

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, data-transformation, stationarity

I have a time series of daily maximum temperature of a city for 2 years 3 months. I removed the seasonality from the data by subtracting present values with the past year values(seasonal differencing). I conducted the Dickey Fuller test and it came out to be stationary. I the tried ARIMA (1,0,7) and ARIMA (1,1,1). But the ARIMA (1,1,1) forecasts are lower in error. How is this possible since differencing a stationary series would cause bad performance right?. Or am I doing something wrong?

(I chose the 1,0,7 and 1,1,1 by looking at the ACF and PACF of the seasonal differenced data and it's first difference)

[image: ACF and PACF of seasonal differenced data]

[image: ACF and PACF of seasonal differenced data's first difference]

ACF and PACF of seasonal differenced data (image 1)

ACF and PACF of seasonal differenced data's first difference (image 2)

Comment: Image one suggests non-stationarity to me. It is declining very slowly. Try running autoarima and see what it says the model is. Some suggest that for mixed models using ACF and PACF in the classical way does not work. Also it is suggested that having values higher than 2 or 3 in social science data (if that is what you have) is rarely right and can be better met by a simpler model so the 7 is doubtful. I am not certain what you mean by error. How did you test the model. Did you use a hold out data set.

Comment: As an aside time series is rarely perfect. I have had models, not ARIMA, that were factually incorrect in their assumptions predict better than factually correct models. It may be that an "error" in your model is dealing with something you have not considered (like a variable) and thus making it better than a "correct" model.

Comment: I split the dataset into train and test and then checked the error of the forecast with the actual temperatures

Comment: I think then you discovered that classical ARIMA like probably all time series is not perfect. Sometimes bad, even illogical models will predict better than "good" ones. Things change between the past and future. Or there may be external variables not in your model.

Comment: Ohh, I guess this would be a case of that